# Sign SOAP messages with personnal signing application

Tags: web-services, security, soap, digital-signature, wss4j

I'm using WSS4J interceptors to sign my SOAP requests.
I would like to know if it's possible to configure the outInterceptor to sign the requests with my own java signing program.